# How to swap a view's template and remove the old view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have the following code:

```
switch (type) {
    case "countdown":
        this.render(_this.templates.countdown);
        break;
    case "timer":
        this.render(_this.templates.timer);
        if (App.Views.timer) App.Views.timer.remove();
        App.Views.timer = new Timer();
        break;
}
```

So, as I suppose when the template were rendered we're remove previous View, because the link on new DOM element changed. But I'm not sure what old view was really removed.

Because if I add `console.log(App.Views.timer)` after `if (App.Views.timer) App.Views.timer.remove();` I get: `child {cid: "view3", $el: jQuery.fn.init(1), el: div#timer.timer}`. And it's look like nothing changed!

I have two questions.

1. Is it correct way to remove view from memory?
2. If I have a div which can change template, is it a correct way to create new View? Unfortunately, the solution to just hide the template does not suit my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What does the view's `remove` function do?

[View's `remove` function](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) just removes the element from the DOM while unbinding any DOM related events and Backbone specific events.

> Removes a view and its `el` from the DOM, and calls [`stopListening`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) to
>   remove any bound events that the view has [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)'d.

The [code for the `remove` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/0eca92f441f63091f3cab0fc900fa21afbfc55fe/backbone.js#L1336-L1342) is:

> ```
> // Remove this view by taking the element out of the DOM, and removing any
> // applicable Backbone.Events listeners.
> remove: function() {
>   this._removeElement();
>   this.stopListening();
>   return this;
> },
> ```

## About the view still in memory

So it still lives in memory until you release any references left. Logging the view object to the console keeps it alive as it's a reference to it.

## Sharing a div for multiple views

I wouldn't go your way on this. Instead of a switch case, you could use a [Backbone Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) with routes and then make yourself some kind of layout view.

A super simple layout view could look like this:

```
var LayoutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // caching the jQuery object on init
        this.$content = this.$('#content');
    },
    setContent: function(view) {
        var content = this.content;
        if (content) content.remove();
        content = this.content = view;
        this.$content.html(content.render().el);
    },
});
```

Used within a router:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'about': 'aboutRoute',
        'contact': 'contactRoute',
        // put the catch-all last
        '*home': 'homeRoute',
    },
    initialize: function() {
        // create the layout once here
        this.layout = new views.Application({
            el: 'body',
        });
    },
    homeRoute: function() {
        var view = new views.Home();
        this.layout.setContent(view);
    },
    aboutRoute: function() {
        var view = new views.About();
        this.layout.setContent(view);
    },
    contactRoute: function() {
        var view = new views.Contact();
        this.layout.setContent(view);
    }
});
```

I wrote a detailed answer on [how to use a router with a simple layout view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082149/1218980).

Comment: My mistake, I did not say that view change by select field, not link. But i think the second part will be usefull for others.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin the same concept applies, don't change the template of a view, change the view within this view using the `setContent` trick.